# how get value of XYZ if it's available in object into array into object looks like {[{XYZ}}} in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

In React I want to get the values of XYZ property in an array of objects with map method. Example:

```js
const data = { 
    message: [ 
        { XYZ: 'Hi' },
        { XYZ: 'Hello' },
        { XYZ: 'How Are You' }
    ],
    number: '121212121'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do de following in your jsx returned by the component:

```js
 {data.message.map(({XYZ}) => {
  return (<span>{XYZ}</span>)
 }
)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```